# Automatically delete items from subscriptions database after they have expired?

Tags: python, django, paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I am creating a website were user can subscribe packages for one month (Pretty much the same as newsletter subscription 5$/month).  how can i manage these subscription packages. whether i need to delete the item permanently after the expiration date? what is the best method.

#### models.py

```
class avail_packs(models.Model):
    pack_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pack_description = models.TextField()
    pack_duration_days = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pack_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)      

class selected_packs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(avail_packs)
    activation_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)        
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

assume there is a pack say bronze

```
pack_name=bronze
pack_description='1000 newsletters'
pack_duration_days=30
pack_cost=9.9$
```

if user activated a pack

```
user= User.objects.get(username='suhail')
pack= avail_packs.objects.get(pack_name=bronze)
activation_date= 27-aug-2013
quantity=1
```

#### now my question is what i want to do the item in selected pack on date `26-sep-2013`?

do i need to delete the item(delete item from selected_packs where `today-activation_date>29`).

#### if i want to delete the item then how?

do i need to run a cron(`django celery`) and check every day to delete these items.

or do i need to delete the item when user clicked the newletter(or some chargable items)

#### i am using paypal so is there any method in paypal to do these types of monthly subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running celery for such a simple task is oversized. Take a look at [django management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run a cronjob every night to deactivate/delete packages.

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--delete',
            action='store_true',
            dest='delete',
            default=False,
            help='Delete inactive packages'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        if options['delete']:
            selected_packs.objects.filter(activation_date__lt=timeframe).delete()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am also using django-registration. it works like when a user first signup, an activation mail will sent to user email. if he doesn't activated with in 7 days, he will not able to activate it by clicking activation link. the inactive userfield will not deleted from database, so the problem is a new user try to signup with the username of that inactive account he will not able to signup. is it a bug on django registration??. can i use these management commands to delete the inactive user??

Comment: django-registration comes with a management command to delete expired users: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/management/commands/cleanupregistration.py?at=default

Comment: thank you verymuch. i am struggling with how to delete these.